# Apply control group rule to specific (or all) Docker containers in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cgroups

By default Docker containers are unprivileged. Of course devices can be added individually with `docker run --device /dev/abc0` but this cannot yet be done in Kubernetes.

In any event I have an arbitrary number of devices per node, which makes it easier to map `/dev` and to enable a cgroup rule: `docker run -v /dev:/dev --device-cgroup-rule='c 123:* rmw'`. How can I pass this `--device-cgroup-rule` to specific or all Docker containers controlled by Kubernetes? Can a RuntimeClass help? A system-level cgroup config?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you should focus on Kublet, it's support for several container runtimes and it's integration with Docker.

According to this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/), there are plenty of options to choose from, like:

> ```
> --cgroup-driver string
> ```
>
> Driver that the kubelet uses to manipulate cgroups on the host.

---

> ```
> --cgroup-root string
> ```
>
> Optional root cgroup to use for pods. This is handled by the container
>   runtime on a best effort basis. Default: '', which means use the
>   container runtime default.

---

> ```
> --enforce-node-allocatable stringSlice
> ```
>
> A comma separated list of levels of node allocatable enforcement to be
>   enforced by kubelet. Acceptable options are 'pods', 'system-reserved'
>   & 'kube-reserved'. If the latter two options are specified,
>   '`--system-reserved-cgroup`' & '`--kube-reserved-cgroup`' must also be set
>   respectively. See
>   `/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/` for more
>   details. (default [pods])

---

> ```
> --runtime-cgroups string
> ```
>
> Optional absolute name of cgroups to create and run the runtime in.

---

Please look into them and verify if they satisfy your needs.

Please let me know if that helped.